# Links wont work the same in IE

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have built a module for galleries, here you have 2 examples, at the bottom of the page:

http://www.we-do.com/referenzen/watch-your-web/

As you see, in modern borwsers, clicking anywhere in the box will open the lightbox, but in IE 7 and 8 has completely different behaviours. How could I normalize it?

Comment: Thanks :) Props to the designer. Im just the developer ;)

Comment: It could come from `:first-child` Have you tried a pseudo-class instead of ?

Comment: first-child is compatible with IE7 and IE8. It shouldnt be the problem.

Comment: I was thinking about the combo `:first-child` / HTML5 Doctype. IE is known for be strict with Doctypes. Could be an issue, but I don't really know.

Comment: Your module is working on IE. you may try it visiting http://www.we-do.com/referenzen/watch-your-web/#prettyPhoto[group234]/0/. when i clicked red + icon it works also IE7 & IE8. maybe you should give a chance to @samsamX suggestion

Comment: Yes it is working, but the link should be as wide and tall as the whole module, not just the "+" sign. (as it does in chrome and firefox). I have tried with using other classes and it doesnt make any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dirty hack for IE7 and IE8,

**CSS**

```
/* IE Fixes */

html.ie7 .gallery-links, html.ie8 .gallery-links { 
    background: url("http://triggertek.com/r/transparent_png/pixel.png") repeat; 
} // i used 1px transparent png to solve it.
```